# Ionic2 ion-select with search bar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to create an ionic select that has a search bar within it, is that possible and how can I do it?
I also tried to create an alert that contains a search input and a radio options inside it and i couldn't do so, may because i can't mix different input types inside the same alert.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I found another workaround to do this, i used the **PopoverController** instead of the alert and it allows me to add a component inside (in my case its name **AutoCompleteSearchPage**) it which contains the search bar and the list and what ever i need to use there

```js
import {
  PopoverController
}
  
from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {



    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(AutoCompleteSearchPage, {
      
      dataContext: this.DataContext,
      autocomplete: this,
      ispopover: true,
    });
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
```

the html template for the search page:

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
          {{LookUpTableName}}
      </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="runSearch($event,viewmodel)" style="padding:5px"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
                               pullingText="Pull to refresh"
                               refreshingSpinner="circles"
                               refreshingText="Refreshing...">
        </ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of dataList" (click)="selectItem(item)">
            {{item?.Name}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles"
                                     loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to have multiple select

Comment: Hi, you can use a checkbox instead of the button inside the list and bind it to an array to store the selected (on select add the item to the array, unselect remove it)  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/

Comment: Hi @Islam I was wondering how you could make the ion-select component open a custom popover instead of the alert/popover with the option values?

Comment: Hi @Mario in my case I created a custom component and i didn't use the ion-select one, i used an ion button  with an icon

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reflect-metadata/0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/zone.js/master/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.8/bundles/ionic.system.js"></script>

    <link href="https://npmcdn.com/ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.8/bundles/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- this Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
    <ion-app></ion-app>

    <script>
      System.import('app.ts')
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Live Demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/BX323jPnqfgGTZCU1Ta3?p=preview

Comment: OP is asking about Ionic 2 not v1

Comment: oh) maybe this you help http://plnkr.co/edit/BX323jPnqfgGTZCU1Ta3?p=preview

Comment: edit your answer and add the right code..

Comment: thanks for the reply :), i need it to run inside an Alert like the ion-select popup, is that possible?

Comment: @Islam I do not know, write this question to the developers, they quickly respond